# Sort Object Class Of Arrays In Java

Tags: java

This is my class, I want to sort each object from it based on `url_Tsim`

```
public class Topic1000Url 
{
    int [] url_id;
    String [] url_topicname ;
    int [] url_Tlink ;
    double [] url_Tsim ;
}
```

where my first obj Topic1000Url data is:

```
1   1   Cloud Computing 0.7291193274375957
2   1   Cloud Computing 0.46815342617565325
3   1   Cloud Computing 0.2859417638141173
4   1   Cloud Computing 0.37506232384399313
5   1   Cloud Computing 0.7474019872077191
6   2   Cloud Computing 0.4754049861628243
7   2   Cloud Computing 0.5268857610773507
8   2   Cloud Computing 0.5268880992116851
9   2   Cloud Computing 0.6113015175585574
10  2   Cloud Computing 0.0
11  3   Cloud Computing 0.5928395545371988
12  3   Cloud Computing 0.0
13  3   Cloud Computing 0.0
14  3   Cloud Computing 0.09418543480859422
15  3   Cloud Computing 0.22015199354179826
```

can any one help me please :)

Comment: Make your class implement `Comparable ` interface.

Comment: What is your comparison logic? If I have two Topic1000Url objects, how do I know which one comes first when I sort them?

Comment: Actually i have 10 Topic1000Url objects , They represent 10 different Topics data " cloud computing , data mining ,  ........."  >> I read them from a file                                   each Topic has 1000 link, i want to sort those those links for each Topic based on similarity Url_Tsim , split the array and perform some caculations.                                                      Cloud comuting (Topic) has 1000(link) each link has (id,Url_Tsim ) , i want to sort each topic based on similarity.                                               I know which one comes first from my file.

Answer (score 0):

You want to sort your list based on a double value `URL_Tsim`...You can use a `comparator` interface as below for sorting your list of values.

```
 Collections.sort(myList, new Comparator<Topic1000Url>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Topic1000Url url1, Topic1000Url url2) {
        return Double.compare(url1.getUrl_Tsim(), url2.getUrl_Tsim());
    }
});
```

Read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) to know more about the `Comparator`.